# I created two openVPN servers on Ubuntu 18.04 which is creating problems - how do I get rid of 1 of them? Must I uninstall and re-install

Tags: 18.04, server, openvpn

I am new to openVPN and am trying to get to understand it better I created 2 servers which is creating a problem as they seem to conflict. I have removed the second servers config, ca and key file  and I have - `sudo systemctl disable openvpn@server2` - however I still get

```
● openvpn@server2.service - OpenVPN connection to server2
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; indirect; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
```

when I run  `sudo systemctl status openvpn@server2`.
How can I completely remove server2

```
Units
UNIT                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION              
accounts-daemon.service               loaded active running Accounts Service         
acpid.service                         loaded active running ACPI event daemon        
anydesk.service                       loaded active running AnyDesk                  
avahi-daemon.service                  loaded active running Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack  
bolt.service                          loaded active running Thunderbolt system service
clean-mount-point@media-jeremy-MacMini_2.service loaded active running Clean the /medi
colord.service                        loaded active running Manage, Install and Genera
cron.service                          loaded active running Regular background program
cups-browsed.service                  loaded active running Make remote CUPS printers 
cups.service                          loaded active running CUPS Scheduler           
dbus.service                          loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus 
fwupd.service                         loaded active running Firmware update daemon   
gdm.service                           loaded active running GNOME Display Manager    
irqbalance.service                    loaded active running irqbalance daemon        
kerneloops.service                    loaded active running Tool to automatically coll
lvm2-lvmetad.service                  loaded active running LVM2 metadata daemon     
ModemManager.service                  loaded active running Modem Manager            
networkd-dispatcher.service           loaded active running Dispatcher daemon for syst
NetworkManager.service                loaded active running Network Manager          
nmbd.service                          loaded active running Samba NMB Daemon         
openvpn@server1.service               loaded active running OpenVPN connection to serv
packagekit.service                    loaded active running PackageKit Daemon        
polkit.service                        loaded active running Authorization Manager    
rsyslog.service                       loaded active running System Logging Service   
rtkit-daemon.service                  loaded active running RealtimeKit Scheduling Pol
smbd.service                          loaded active running Samba SMB Daemon         
snapd.service                         loaded active running Snappy daemon            
ssh.service                           loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell serve
systemd-journald.service              loaded active running Journal Service          
systemd-logind.service                loaded active running Login Service            
systemd-resolved.service              loaded active running Network Name Resolution  
systemd-timesyncd.service             loaded active running Network Time Synchronizati
systemd-udevd.service                 loaded active running udev Kernel Device Manager
thermald.service                      loaded active running Thermal Daemon Service   
udisks2.service                       loaded active running Disk Manager             
unattended-upgrades.service           loaded active running Unattended Upgrades Shutdo
upower.service                        loaded active running Daemon for power managemen
user@1000.service                     loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000
whoopsie.service                      loaded active running crash report submission da
wpa_supplicant.service                loaded active running WPA supplicant           

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

40 loaded units listed. Pass --all to see loaded but inactive units, too.
To show all installed unit files use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
```

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl --type=service --state=running list-units` ? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Thanks have done so

Comment: I only see one openvpn server running in the list of services. What else do you want to achieve?

Comment: $     tail -100 /var/log/syslog gives an error

 Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/server.conf
So I seem to have a problem on my server set-up. Possibly because of setting-up server 2 then deleting files